# jQuery Mobile custom styled horizontal responsive menu

Tags: css, internet-explorer, jquery-mobile, internet-explorer-11

I try to create a custom styled horizontal menu built with a controlgroup and some checkboxes (its pre-enhanced, but does not matter for the question). 
What i need is a horizontal elastic menu only on one row for mobile screens and a fixed maximum width for large screens:

```
  <div class="color-menu">
    <div class="ui-controlgroup-controls">
      <div class="ui-checkbox">
        <input name="cl-1" id="cl-1" type="checkbox" data-corners="false" data-enhanced="true" value="electric-green" />
        <label for="cl-1" id="lab-cl-1" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left"></label>
      </div>
      ... some other choices
    </div>
  </div>
```

While this seems to be render perfect in FF & Chrome, it behaves strange in IE11, which is still in my browser target (i don't tested it in other more recent Edge versions):

FF & Chrome:
[image: Good]

IE11:

[image: Bad]

This is the relevant CSS part:

```
.color-menu {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.color-menu .ui-controlgroup-controls {
  display: inline-block !important;
}

.color-menu .ui-controlgroup-controls .ui-checkbox {
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  max-width: 12.5%;
  /* 100%/8 */
}
```

Its seems an issue related to max-width or display: block, but i'm not able to solve this issue.

Where is the problem here?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p7es287b/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how i solved it:
I changed the markup according to the jQuery Mobile demos 1.4.5 - also the controlgroup could be pre-rendered:

```
  <div class="color-menu">
    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-enhanced="true" class="ui-controlgroup ui-corner-all">
      <div class="ui-controlgroup-controls ui-shadow">
        <div class="ui-checkbox">
          <input name="cl-1" id="cl-1" type="checkbox" data-enhanced="true" data-corners="false" value="electric-green" />
          <label for="cl-1" id="lab-cl-1" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left"></label>
        </div>
        ...some other choices
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Style: i'm using now width instead of max-width for the controlgroup controls.

```
.color-menu .ui-controlgroup-controls .ui-checkbox {
    float: left;
    clear: none;
    width: 12.5%; /* 100% / number of choices */
}
```

The uneven sporadic issue with IE is gone.